# Group countries together and count

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have a table like this:

```
-------------------------------
EMP ID|Country    |Emp Level  |
------|-----------|-----------|
102   |UK         |Staff      |
103   |US         |Admin Staff|
104   |CA         |Staff      |
105   |NL         |Admin Staff|
106   |MN         |Intern     |
107   |IN         |Staff      |
108   |UK         |Staff      |
109   |US         |Admin Staff|
110   |IN         |Admin Staff|
------------------------------
```

I need to count number of employees in each category in each country given following condition: If country is not in `('UK' or 'US' or 'CA')` then consider it as 'Global'. So our answer should be:

```
------------------------------
|Country    |Emp Level  |Count|
|-----------|-----------|-----
|UK         |Staff      |2
|US         |Admin Staff|2
|CA         |Staff      |1
|Global     |Admin Staff|2
|Global     |Intern     |1
|Global     |Staff      |1
```

So far I can count number of staff in each category, in each country but cannot club the countries not in given set and count & display them as global.

Comment: Can you post the schema with sample data?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT   Country, EmpLevel, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM     my_table
WHERE    Country IN ('UK', 'US', 'CA')
GROUP BY Country, EmpLevel

UNION

SELECT   'Global', EmpLevel, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM     my_table
WHERE    Country NOT IN ('UK', 'US', 'CA')
GROUP BY EmpLevel
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c44a/1/0).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
select country as cou, emp_level as emp, count(*)
from your_table
where country in ('UK', 'US', 'CA')
group by cou, emp
order by cou, emp
union
select 'global', emp_level as emp, count(*)
from your_table
where country not in ('UK', 'US', 'CA')
group by emp
order by emp
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  
    CASE WHEN Country IN ('UK', 'US', 'CA') THEN Country ELSE 'Global' END
      AS Country,
    EmpLevel, 
    COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM
    tableX
GROUP BY 
    CASE WHEN Country IN ('UK', 'US', 'CA') THEN Country ELSE 'Global' END, 
    EmpLevel ;
```

---

There will be a difference in the results between this query and the one by @eggyal and @duffymo - if there are rows with `NULL` in column `Country`. This query will count those rows in the `'Global'` groups, the other query will not count them at all.

Comment: +1 Good point about `NULL` (although one could just add `OR Country IS NULL` into the relevant filter criteria if so desired); that said, I still prefer the `UNION` approach as it can use indexes to perform the filtering & grouping (whereas I think your version cannot?).

Comment: @eggyal I'm not sure if my query will use indexes - or if it does so efficiently. The UNION answer is more likely to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this would work (Untested, and might need some more work)

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Country NOT IN ('US','UK','CA') THEN 'Global' ELSE Country, Emp_Level, COUNT(*)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY Country, Emp_Level
```